# Default value should be stored at insertion

Tags: sql

I have a question which I was asked in an interview.
My question is:

I created one table called "`EMPLOYEE`", with fields `emplno`, `emplname`, `joiningdate` with `NOT NULL` constraint.
Here when I inserted employee details as `'101','suresh','2014'`. (By mistake I inserted 2014 instead of 2013).
So now the '`2013`' (Present year) value should be inserted instead of '`2014`'.

and for this question I couldn't answer. Can you help me understand what it should be?

Comment: Are you looking to update the existing row, set a default for new rows added in the future, or not allowing the user to add a row that isn't the current year?

Comment: Are you looking for trigger or autocorrection?

Comment: My requirement is when I insert a new row, that row should be inserted but joining year should be current year(2013), even I entered 2014 or 2010 or anything.

Comment: @Bridge Set a default column for the new rows added in the feature, means the new row should be inserted at the same time the joiningdate column should be auto corrected.

Comment: @pratibha Is this possible with triggers or autocorrection?

Comment: @SureshAppu You could create a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the table, that sets your column to `YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the table,

```
UPDATE employee
SET joiningdate = '2013'
WHERE emplno = 101
AND emplname = 'suresh';

COMMIT;
```

Comment: My requirement is when I insert a new row, that row should be inserted but joining year should be current year(2013), even I entered 2014 or 2010 or anything.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer you can also create table with computed column

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE
 (
  emplno int,
  emplname nvarchar(10),
  joiningdate AS YEAR(GETDATE())
  )
```

and then INSERT statement will be

```
INSERT dbo.EMPLOYEE
VALUES ('101', 'suresh')
```

OR table with DEFAULT constraint

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EMPLOYEE
 (
  emplno int,
  emplname nvarchar(10),
  joiningdate nvarchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT YEAR(GETDATE())
  ) 

INSERT dbo.EMPLOYEE
VALUES ('101', 'suresh', DEFAULT)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9709a/2)